# Convert milli seconds to day-normalized javax.xml.datatype.Duration

Tags: java, xml, duration

I need to convert a duration given in milli seconds => type `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`.
The problem with that type is, that it uses years and months as fields (whose duration is dependent on the current timestamp).

That being said, I want to normalize the `javax.xml.datatype.Duration` to only contain days (edit: of course, also hours, minutes, ...).
This is possible like so:

```
private static Duration millis2Duration(final long millis) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    Duration duration = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration(millis);
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
    return duration.normalizeWith(cal);
}
```

But it seems rather strange to create a calendar in order to normalize the duration. Am I missing something, or is this the best way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
java.time.Duration.ofMillis( m ).toDaysPart()
```

## Avoid legacy date-time types

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Never use `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `java.util.Date`, and such.

## `java.time.Duration`

Use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) rather than [`javax.xml.datatype.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/Duration.html).

```java
Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis( yourCountOfMillisecondsGoesHere ) ;
```

Apparently you want a count of generic 24-hour days without regard for dates. The `java.time.Duration` class can [give you that](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toDaysPart()).

```java
long countOf24HourDays = duration.toDaysPart() ;
```

No need for you to create a formal method of your own. Wherever you need it, just use:

```java
Duration.ofMillis( m ).toDaysPart()
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I am explicitly asking for javax.xml.datatype. It is not in my hand to choose another datatype. Also: the Duration#toDaysPart just returns the plain days?! Edit: ahh okay, sorry. I edited the description above. The duration should of course also contain hours, minutes, ...

Answer (score 0):

### Use java.time also when you need javax.xml.datatype.Duration

> I am explicitly asking for javax.xml.datatype. It is not in my hand to
> choose another datatype.

The conversion from `java.time.Duration` to a `javax.xml.datatype.Duration` fulfilling your requirements may not be exactly trivial, but I still prefer it as the easiest to understand and safest way to obtain what you want.

```
    long millis = 21_098_765_432L;

    boolean positive = millis > 0;
    java.time.Duration javaTimeDuration = java.time.Duration.ofMillis(millis);
    if (! positive) {
        javaTimeDuration = javaTimeDuration.negated();
    }
    BigDecimal seconds = BigDecimal.valueOf(javaTimeDuration.toSecondsPart())
            .add(BigDecimal.valueOf(javaTimeDuration.getNano(), 9))
            .stripTrailingZeros();
    Duration dur = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration(
            positive,
            null,
            null,
            BigInteger.valueOf(javaTimeDuration.toDays()),
            BigInteger.valueOf(javaTimeDuration.toHoursPart()),
            BigInteger.valueOf(javaTimeDuration.toMinutesPart()),
            seconds);

    System.out.println(dur);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> P244DT4H46M5.432S

What I like about the code is that it is explicit about using the days, hours, minutes and seconds including fraction of second from the java.time duration and constructing an XML duration without years and months.

Some of the trouble comes from the fact that the only way to pass fraction of second to a factory method is through `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`. So I am first constructing a `BigDecimal` holding seconds and fraction of second.

The `toHoursPart`, `toMinutesPart` and `toSecondsPart` methods I am using were added in Java 9.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.